# How to use the user provided city and reply using it ? Using if

Tags: python, chatbot

**I want the user to ask Whats the weather in Mumbai and the bot should reply the weather in Mumbai is amazing**

```
# i want the %s in the if statement to be blank for user to input his city and ask for weather
def chatbot(n):
if n=='whats the weather in %s': #the user can enter anything in place of %s
    print('the weather in %s is amazing')#%s means like the user enter whats the weather in mumbai

print("BOT: HEY IM CHATBOT MAY I KNOW YOUR NAME?")
a=input('YOU:')
print("BOT: Hi",a.upper())
while True:
print("BOT: ASK ME SOMETHING",a.upper(), "\U0001F642 OR PRESS q TO EXIT!")
n=input("YOU:").lower()
if n != 'q':
    chatbot(n)
else:
    print("BOT: BYE :)")
    break
```

I hope you understand and sorry for my formatting errors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works using the `%` operator to replace the `%s` placeholders, however this solution relies on the last word of the string passed to the `chatbot()` method being the name of the city

```
def chatbot(n):
    city = n.split(" ")[-1]
    if n=='whats the weather in %s' % city:
        print('the weather in %s is amazing' % city)

chatbot("whats the weather in mumbai")
```

Comment: hey brother thanks for your help what does [-1] does

Comment: The [-1] gets the last element, so in this case the string is split on the spaces to get the individual words then the last word is selected